# Recursive Function to find all Point-Connections

Tags: c#, recursion

I have a List with all possible Points that exists inside a List. Now i want to loop over those, to find all possible combinations i can do with them.

So if i have the points 1,2,3 (and 0, the start), i want to get the lists

0123

0132

0231

0213

0312

0321

but somehow, my code only runs through it once, and thus only prints 0123 at the end.

When i try to comment out the first CalcPoints(CurrentPathID);, it will reach the else statement, else it never even goes there.

Here i s a complete example on a standalone i tried on dotnetfiddle.net
https://dotnetfiddle.net/VFFTxS

The Code:

````
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;


public class Program
{
    public static List<List<int>> AllPointConnections = new List<List<int>>();
    public static List<int> AllPoints = new List<int>();
    public static int MaxConnectionsCount = 0;

    public static void CalcPoints(int CurrentPathID){
        Console.WriteLine("Call CalcPoints with {0:D}", CurrentPathID);
        bool AddedPoint = false;
        for(var i = 0; i < AllPoints.Count; i++) {
            bool CanAddPoint = true;
            for(var z = 0; z < AllPointConnections[CurrentPathID].Count; z++) {
                if(AllPointConnections[CurrentPathID][z] == AllPoints[i]){
                        CanAddPoint = false;
                }
            }

            if(CanAddPoint){
                Console.WriteLine("Point to can add: {0:D}", AllPoints[i]);
                if(!AddedPoint){
                    Console.WriteLine("Its a first point");
                    AddedPoint = true;
                    AllPointConnections[CurrentPathID].Add(AllPoints[i]);
                    CalcPoints(CurrentPathID);
                }else{
                    Console.WriteLine("Its a second point");                    
                    List<int> NewPath = new List<int>(AllPointConnections[CurrentPathID]);

                    NewPath.Add(AllPoints[i]);
                    AllPointConnections.Add(NewPath);
                    MaxConnectionsCount++;                  
                    CalcPoints(MaxConnectionsCount);                    
                }
            }   
        }

        if(!AddedPoint){
            Console.Write("Finished a Path. Points: ");
            for(var q = 0; q < AllPointConnections[CurrentPathID].Count;q++) {
                Console.Write("{0:D}", AllPointConnections[CurrentPathID][q]);
            }
            Console.Write("\n");
        }

    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        AllPoints.Add(1);
        AllPoints.Add(2);
        AllPoints.Add(3);

        List<int> StartPath = new List<int>();
        StartPath.Add(0);
        AllPointConnections.Add(StartPath);
        CalcPoints(0);
    }
}```

Idk whats wrong, it should loop over all Paths and prints all combinations, but it somehow never returns. I never see the console message "Its a second point"

Anyone can point out whats wrong?
````

Comment: The problem is with this line : List<int> NewPath = new List<int>(AllPointConnections[CurrentPathID]);  You keep on overwritten old values so you only have the last results.

Answer (score 0):

Targeting simplicity not efficiency, this:

```
  class Program
  {
    static List<List<int>> Combos(List<int> listIn)
    {
      switch (listIn.Count)
      {
        case 0 : return new List<List<int>>();
        case 1 : return new List<List<int>> { listIn };
        default:
          var retList = new List<List<int>>();
          for (var i = 0; i < listIn.Count; i++)
          {
            var item = listIn[i];
            listIn.RemoveAt(i);
            var combos = Combos(listIn);
            foreach (var oneCombo in combos)
            {
              var returnCombo = new List<int> { item };
              returnCombo.AddRange(oneCombo);
              retList.Add(returnCombo);
            }
            listIn.Insert(i, item);
          }
          return retList;
      }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      foreach (var l in Combos(new List<int>{1,2,3}))
      {
        foreach (var i in l)
          Console.Write($"{i} ");
        Console.WriteLine();
      }
      Console.ReadKey();
    }
  }
```

gives this:

```
1 2 3
1 3 2
2 1 3
2 3 1
3 1 2
3 2 1
```